# Publishing image using the Graph API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to publish a photo on user wall via file upload like in this example from Facebook open graph.

```
/* make the API call */ FB.api(
"/me/photos",
"POST",
{
    "source": "{image-data}"
},
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
} );
```

i cant understand what they mean with the "image data" parameter 
can anyone clearly to me what its mean?

Answer (score 0):

in php

use `'image' => '@' . $img`  and `$img = realpath('imgPath');`  it will work fine

Notice that it will make load on your server and request will take about 1.5 -> 2.5 MB ..

You can also share by link using parameter 'url' it will take 1kb .